# Cleanup for expiring hash maps

Tags: caching, hashmap, guava, concurrenthashmap

I need a data structure that runs a piece of code after the the key-value pair expires. For example, I have a key and a connection Object stored in the expiring hashmap. I need this expiring hashmap to run a function that takes the takes connObj as arguement and closes the connection after the key-value pair has expired.

I have explored PassiveExpiringMap by Apache and Guava.MapMaker by Google but I dont see any cleanup functionality, does anyone have any ways to do this?

Comment: Guava Cache offers a removal listener for this callback. Like Apache, it is passive so the clean up only occurs due to other activity on the cache. The successor library, Caffeine, offers a scheduler option if you want a thread that cleans up immediately when the entry expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exploring, I found this expiring hashmap by Jodah quite helpful - https://jodah.net/expiringmap/javadoc/net/jodah/expiringmap/ExpiringMap.html

The data structure uses an asynchronous expiration listener. My implementation was something like this

```
Map<String, Connections> ConnMap = ExpiringMap.builder()
          .maxSize(100000)
          .expiration(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
          .expirationPolicy(ExpirationPolicy.ACCESSED)
          .expirationListener((key, connObject) -> {
                System.out.println("Closing connObject->key: " + key + " connObj: " + connObject);
                connObject.close();
        })
          .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @BenManes in the comment (Caffeine's creator), see the example from https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Cleanup (emphasis mine):

> By default, Caffeine does not perform cleanup and evict values "automatically" or instantly after a value expires. Instead, it performs small amounts of maintenance work after write operations or occasionally after read operations if writes are rare. If your cache is high-throughput then you don't have to worry about performing cache maintenance to clean up expired entries and the like. **If your cache is read and written to rarely, you may wish to leverage an external thread, as described below**, that calls `Cache.cleanUp()` when appropriate.
>
> ```
> LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
>     .scheduler(Scheduler.systemScheduler())
>     .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
>     .build(key -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
> ```
>
> **A Scheduler may be provided to enable prompt removal of expired entries.** The scheduling between expiration events is paced to exploit batching and to minimize executions in short succession. The **scheduling is best-effort and does not make any hard guarantees of when an expired entry will be removed**. Java 9+ users may prefer using `Scheduler.systemScheduler()` to leverage the dedicated, system-wide scheduling thread.

More details can be found in the [`Caffeine#scheduler(Scheduler)` javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/latest/com.github.benmanes.caffeine/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine.html#scheduler(com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Scheduler)):

> The scheduling between expiration events is paced to exploit batching and to minimize executions in short succession. This minimum difference between the **scheduled executions is implementation-specific, currently at ~1 second (2^30 ns)**. In addition, the provided scheduler may not offer real-time guarantees (including [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html?is-external=true)). The scheduling is best-effort and does not make any hard guarantees of when an expired entry will be removed.

So if the way scheduler is implemented in Caffeine works for you, you should be good just using [`removalListener`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/latest/com.github.benmanes.caffeine/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine.html#removalListener(com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.RemovalListener)) (or [`evictionListener`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/latest/com.github.benmanes.caffeine/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine.html#evictionListener(com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.RemovalListener))), ex. using types from the sample code above:

```
   .removalListener((Key key, Graph graph, RemovalCause cause) ->
       yourFunction(connObj, key, graph, cause)) // or whatever you need
```